# Use a table's data from a SELECT statement in it's own WHERE statement using the same table's data

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the confusing title. Sadly, the text is even more confusing.

Basically, I have an SQL script that imports data from one table to another, and I'm trying to ignore certain rows.

The first table is recording three rows per 'event,' and I only want one of them. The events I want to ignore are two *almost* duplicates but one column is 0 instead of 1, as well as the time, which could vary. I'm giving it a 20-second limit for it to still match.

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO prism_actions (action_time, action_type, player, world, x, y, z, data)
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`co_blocks`.time), 
    'block-shift', 
    'Piston', 
    CASE WHEN `co_blocks`.wid = 1 THEN 'world' ELSE (CASE WHEN `co_blocks`.wid = 2 THEN 'world_nether' ELSE 'world_the_end' END) END, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `co_blocks`.bcords , '.', 1 ), -- This will get the X coordinate of this action
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `co_blocks`.bcords , '.', 2 ),'.', -1), -- Y coordinate
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `co_blocks`.bcords , '.', 3 ),'.', -1), -- Z
    CONCAT("{\"block_id\":", `co_blocks`.type, ",\"block_data\":", `co_blocks`.data, "}")
  FROM `co_blocks`
  WHERE `co_blocks`.user LIKE '#piston' 
    AND `co_blocks`.action = 1 
    AND NOT (EXISTS(
      SELECT `id` FROM `co_blocks` WHERE user LIKE '#piston' AND action = 0 AND time < (`co_blocks`.time + 20) AND time > (`co_blocks`.time - 20) AND `co_blocks`.bcords LIKE bcords))
  ORDER BY id ASC;
```

The `EXISTS()` in the `WHERE` statement is me trying to check if there is the almost-duplicate record for it.

My issue is, I'm using `co_blocks`.time  to check the time of the first `SELECT`'s column. I don't know if it will use the first `SELECT`'s time or the second.

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `co_blocks` 
WHERE user LIKE '#piston' 
AND action = 0 
AND time < (`co_blocks`.time + 20) 
AND time > (`co_blocks`.time - 20) 
AND `co_blocks`.bcords LIKE bcords
```

It is using the same table name. **How would I use the first `SELECT`'s data for checking in a `WHERE` in the second `SELECT`?**

**EDIT:**
Here is some example data I start with:

```
+------+------+------+------------+---------+------------+------+------+--------+------+------+
| id   | cx   | cz   | time       | user    | bcords     | type | data | action | rb   | wid  |
+------+------+------+------------+---------+------------+------+------+--------+------+------+
| 2147 |   22 |   17 | 1361130494 | #piston | 359.67.276 |    3 |    0 |      1 |    0 |    1 |
| 2148 |   22 |   17 | 1361130494 | #piston | 359.67.276 |    3 |    0 |      0 |    0 |    1 |
| 2149 |   22 |   17 | 1361130494 | #piston | 358.67.276 |    3 |    0 |      1 |    0 |    1 |
```

I would like to only import the data from the last row (the bcords are different and the action=1)

**EDIT 2:**

I should give more context on this. I'm trying to take data from one table, `co_blocks`, and place it into another table, `prism_actions`. The program that uses `prism_actions` only uses one row for this action, while the one that uses `co_blocks` uses 3. I'm just trying to get the correct action from `co_blocks` and put it in `prism_actions`.

**EDIT 3:**

Here's another example of what I'm having issues with, hopefully it will make it easier to understand. In my table there are values, and I want to have two statements that compare info from each table against each other.

```
UPDATE co_pistons
    SET x = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( bcords , '.', 1 ) FROM `co_pistons` WHERE 
    `co_pistons`.bcords LIKE bcords
    LIMIT 1)
    WHERE NOT isFrom;
```

On line 3 of this, `co_pistons`.bcords and `bcords` refer to the same thing. I want `co_pistons`.bcords to refer to the `UPDATE`'s bcords, so I can compare them against each other.

Comment: Be more specific about which db you are using.

Comment: Can you give us a chart of the data and a chart of the desired results

Comment: if I understand your question correctly the time in your subquery will only be used in the subquery. the time you're inserting into `prism_actions` will be from your main query

Comment: I'm using MySQL, it looks like it says: `Server version: 5.1.66 Source distribution` when I connect

Comment: @Luke101 Okay, I've edited my question with the data I start with.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I'm sort of new to SQL, I'm not sure what you mean by subsquery. Is that the `SELECT` after the first `INSERT INTO`? Or the `SELECT` in the `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` of the `SELECT`?

Comment: @MattBusche If the main query is the first SELECT, then yes, I'm trying to insert only the data from the main query into `prism_actions`. The data in the sub-query is *only* for checking if I should insert the data in the main query.

Comment: Adding on to my last comment, I'm trying to check things in the sub-query using data from the main query, but I think if I use `co_blocks`.<stuff> then it will just use the sub-query's data and always return true because it's comparing it to itself.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood Luke's question; both tables are in the same database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>As a solution for this, I ended up creating a separate table, and adding in all the data I needed to use. Then, I could compare the table's data in a subquery to the main query's data. I'm not sure if this is too efficient, but for my script it works fine for me, as the script is only run once. If anyone has any better ideas that would be great, but otherwise this works for me.</strike>

**EDIT**

My issue was actually that I didn't know how to use `AS` to name tables differently. This was causing me to have two tables used in the query with the same name, which ended up confusing me. The solution is to name the tables with nicknames:

```
FROM `co_blocks` as c1
...
SELECT `co_blocks` as c2 WHERE c1.bcords = c2.bcords
```

The previous solution works, I suppose, but it's definitely not the best way to do it.